# How to render item of each page?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating fullstack application. And, i have on backend paginated data, like this:
{
"pageNumber": 1,
"pageSize": 12,
"totalRecords": 172,
"data": [...]
}

Now i need to fetch them on front with pagination also. But, i'm not good with react and dont know how to render.
So, i'm wondering how to display all items from each page?

```
function ProductPage() {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(null)

    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
          const response = await getProducts()
          setProduct(response.data.data)
        }
    
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const response = await getProducts()

            setData(response.data)
            console.log(response.data)
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])

    function handlePageClick({ selected: selectedPage }) {
        setCurrentPage(selectedPage);
    }

    const pageCount = Math.ceil(data.totalRecords / data.pageSize)

    return (
        <div className="content-inner">
            <SortPopup
                items = { sortItems }
            />

            <div className="list__item">
                {
                    product ? product.map(item => 
                        <ProductItem
                            key={ item.id }
                            image={ item.thumbnail }
                            title={ item.label }
                            description={ item.description }
                            price={ item.price }
                            discount="-10%"
                            link={ item.id }
                        />
                    ) : 
                    Array(12)
                    .fill(0)
                    .map((_, index) => (<Loader key={index} />))
                }
            </div>
            
            <ReactPaginate
                previousLabel={"← Previous"}
                nextLabel={"Next →"}
                pageCount={ pageCount }
                onPageChange={ handlePageClick }
                containerClassName={ "pagination" }
                previousLinkClassName={ "pagination__link" }
                nextLinkClassName={ "pagination__link" }
                disabledClassName={ "pagination__link--disabled" }
                activeClassName={ "pagination__link--active" }
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Btw, i'm using react-paginate lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass the value that comes from handlePageClick to your api and update the products state

```
const handlePageClick = (val) => {
    fetchPaginatedData({
        pageNumber: val.selected + 1
    });
};


const getProducts = (query) => {
    fetch(url + query, {
        method: 'GET',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return response.json();
}
}


//here you can write your api query to get data from backend
const fetchPaginatedData = (query) => {
    const fetchData = async (query) => {

        //where get products is used to fetch products data 
        const response = await getProducts(query)
        setProduct(response.data.data)
    }
};
```

I have tried to create a solution to your problem without using any backend , use it for any reference

[image: Edit friendly-gareth-gxiyc]